# Can I add a single point to a graph in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, charts

In Excel 2010, how do I graph a specific point on a graph that already has a line graphed on it. This specific point is from a different data set and does not fall on the line.

Comment: Could you be a little more specific? What have you tried?

Comment: This may help: http://www.youtube.com/user/ExcelIsFun

Comment: @pnuts Its certainly helped me alot with excel, and i would never have known about it, had it not been recommended to me by someone else

Comment: @pnuts thx for your thoughts

Answer (score 2):

A "quick fix" might be simply to overlay a marker using Insert, Shapes (green diamond in example). Better would be to use a second "series" of data (brown square in example) so its position would adjust appropriately in response to changes in either axis:

[image: SU517191 example]